# Xcode 4.5 - create a UIWEbView that receives and loads different URL´s

Tags: xcode, url, uiwebview

I´m trying to make my first app. Something very simple, but I need help in one small detail.

This app consist´s in only two screens, the first one with 10 buttons, Each button points to a diferent URL, that should load in the next screen.

At the moment I can load the first URL, from the first button. How can I connect all the buttons in order that in the next screen it load´s that button link/url?

Thanks to everyone that can help me.

Comment: Using the same method you used for the first button?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, your starting with a view with 10 UIButtons, each is linked to open a second UIWebView, with a specific URL, depending on which of the 10 original buttons on the first view was pressed.

From here you can add a back button, to take your user back to the original view of 10 UIButtons by dismissing the second view with something like:

```
       - (IBAction)back:(id)sender {
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
       }
```

Or you can use a segmented control, to switch between all 10 by sliding it.  There's good write up at http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/tutorial-discussion/29597-uisegmentedcontrol-tutoria.html on using it.

I know i'm coming in a little late here, but maybe someone out there has a similar question.  Also check http://www.geekylemon.com  Some good pointers for beginners found there as well.